# intersection number on the boundary of a manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, intersection-theory, manifolds-with-boundary, compact-manifolds

Let $F: W \to N$ be a smooth map, where $W$ is a compact manifold with boundary, $Z \subset N$ is closed and all manifolds are oriented. Also $\partial F \pitchfork Z$ and 
$F^{-1}(Z)$ is a compact, oriented, 1-dimensional manifold diffeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

I would like to show that the intersection numbers of of the two endpoints of this line segment have opposite sign, that is $(\partial F \cdot Z)_x = - (\partial F \cdot Z)_y$  for $\{x, y\} = (\partial F)^{-1}(Z)$.

In the notes that I read we show that $(\partial F \cdot Z)_x = (F^{-1}(Z) \cdot \partial W)_x$ and then the result seems to follow quite intuitively. But to prove this equality we need results that I still have some troubles with (about short exact sequences) and I was wondering if there is an easier way to get the same result.

Comment: What definition of intersection number are you using?

Comment: $(F \cdot Z)_x = 1$ if $d_xF(T_xW)$ and $T_{F(x)}Z$  have postitive intersection in  $T_{F(x)}N$ and $-1$ if they have negative intersection.

Comment: And having positive (or negative) intersection means that if you combine two positively oriented bases of $d_xF(T_xW)$ and $T_{F(x)}Z$ you get a positively (negatively) oriented basis for $T_{F(x)}N$.

Comment: How comfortable are you with differential forms?

Comment: I have learned recently about them in a course about differentiable manifolds